# Android Relative Layout Align Center

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a List Activities Item Layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:contentDescription="ss"
        android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" android:src="@drawable/marker"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="320" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:text="Place Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the Layout to be displayed as follows.

[image]

i want to align it center Horizontal

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This will work:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="ss"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="320" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:text="Place Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 34):

If you want to make it center then use **`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`** in the TextView.

Comment: my Relative Layout has fill_parent for both height and width. Since this is the layout for an Item inside a ListView i want many of them to stack on top of each other. so do i need to do wrap_contnet to the RelativeView ?

Comment: @HarshaMV actually it doesn't matter because its only for a single item so.

Answer (score 10):

This will definately work for you.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_report_lbAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/btn_back_margin_left"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_edit" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="FlitsLimburg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tv_header_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_refresh_lbAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btn_back_margin_right"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_refresh" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use gravity with aligning top and bottom.

```
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:layout_alignTop="@id/place_category_icon"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@id/place_category_icon"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this in your RelativeLayout

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="ss"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/marker" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Place Name"
            android:textColor="#F00F00"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="320" />
    </TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center an item in a RelativeLayout, you can use the attributes

```
android:foregroundGravity="center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```